# I need help identifying two passive SMD components from [ GoPro Hero+ ]

Tags: identification, surface-mount, passive-components

[[image: ][1]]

This is the bottom side of the GoPro PCB. I marked the components I need identifying. I assume they are either capacitors and/or resistors, but I need confirmation.

[image]

[image: As you can see, the two components are missing and need to be identified and replaced.]

Comment: I don't think this is answerable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These components are SMT components, most likely 0402 size (seeing as there are smaller SMT passives on the board which are probably 0201's).

The device with the mark next to the pulled of SMT's is most likely a sot666 package.

The black one is a resistor.
The tan one is a capacitor.
By the looks of the top layer copper, they are in an RC configuration with both connected to the sot666

There is no way to know the value of a resistor by inspection.
You'll need to measure the resistor with a DMM (in ohms mode) to find its value.

While capacitors do have color codes, in many instances these are manufactuer specific, the best way would be to measure it. It's most likely that the capacitor is lower than 0.1uF in value.

If the intention is to repair the board, then you probably don't need to find new components, just clean the pads off the old components (as they have been ripped off of the board). Scrape the copper off of the traces and find a very very small gauge wire to connect them all back. This will be a difficult repair due to the size of the components.

Comment: Is there any way to find the schematic to the board? Or at least use OCR/OCV to determine the schematic? I don't have the capacitor, just the resistor shown in the picture with the penny for scale.

Comment: I don't think GoPro is going to release their schematics, as that would make it dead simple to copy their hardware and there are a lot of people that want to copy it. The only way would be to reverse engineer the board with another working unit. If you could figure out what that 300 part is that might help also.